# How to reset/undo changes in folder using Magit

Tags: magit

I'm looking for a way to undo changes in selected directory, analogue of `git checkout [folder-path]` in Magit.

I found that I can reset changes of specific file to selected branch by typing `X f` in magit-status, but I didn't find a way to do the same for folders.

Is there a way to achieve that in Magit?

Comment: You can select all the relevant changes in the status buffer, and type `k` to kill them.

Comment: @phils yes but it's still per file rather than entire folder.

Comment: Sure.  But as with `git` itself, `magit` only shows you files rather than directories (the latter being implicit in the former).  If you particularly don't want to deal with files, I would just use `:` to run the git command line you initially mentioned.

Comment: Thanks, I think `:` is what I was looking for.